# TYPO3 Extension Error: Cannot create empty instance of the class

Tags: typo3

My FE plugin created using extension builder shows me the following error :

```
Cannot create empty instance of the class "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage" because it does not implement the TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\DomainObjectInterface.
```

What does it mean and how do I resolve it? 
TYPO3 version 6.1.0

My Domain Object named `Subject` has relations `Category_Id m:n relation` and `Location_Id 1:n relation` . I did not map these two to any table during the creation of the extension.

How do I mention this in the extension that these relations are related to certain tables (`Category_table and Location_table`)and are to be looked in their respective domain model objects to retrieve data ?

The problem is a little confusing, I hope I made myself clear

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up the relation within the `TCA`.

Make sure to clear the cache and to remove the `typo3temp/Cache/`.

Then you will need to `annotate your model` properly such that `extbase` can resolve the reference.

Remember: `TCA` for core and annotation for `extbase`

Comment: I assigned `foreign_table` to the respective tables already. I have no problem there. The issue is to access those domain models through the relations defined.

Comment: If you annotate the relation in the model too, then extbase should resolve the relation manually.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much
Can you please edit your answers for future use :)